# Linking email addresses that aren't already linked

Tags: php, regex, replace

I'm currently matching email addresses with the below regex (and linking them as `mailto` links):

```
/([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,64})/
```

However, I do not want to link anything that has already been linked before as a `mailto` link or within an existing link (eg. index.php?email=example@example.com) otherwise the link gets quite screwed up like the below:

```
<a href="mailto:<a href="mailto:example@example.com">example@example.com</a>"><a href="mailto:example@example.com">example@example.com</a></a>
```

**Update**

Here's an example of PHP I'm using to find the email addresses (sorry, didn't think it was required):

```
$input = "example@example.com<br><br><a href='mailto:example@example.com'>test email</a><br><br><a href='mailto:example@example.com'>example@example.com</a>";

$output = preg_replace("/([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,64})/i", "<a href='mailto:$1'>$1</a>", $input);

//output
<a href="mailto:example@example.com">example@example.com</a><br><br><a mailto:example@example.com'="" href="mailto:&lt;a href=">example@example.com</a>'&gt;test email<br><br><a mailto:example@example.com'="" href="mailto:&lt;a href=">example@example.com</a>'&gt;<a href="mailto:example@example.com">example@example.com</a>
```

**Update 2**

I also have a further regex question (if possible) - I also have the below regex to make all links target to a new window, however, i do not want anything `mailto` linked to go to a new window - is it possible to not target `mailto` links?

```
$output = preg_replace("/<(a)([^>]+)>/i", "<\\1 target=\"_blank\"\\2>", str_replace('target="_blank"', '', $output));
```

Comment: You'll need to provide the code snippet where you actually perform linking. Simple regex pattern is not enough.

Comment: didn't think it was required (as regex is regex), now included

Comment: Not every regex is a regex. Different languages allow different functionalities. For example, lookbehinds work in .NET, but not in JavaScript. That's why we need to know what language you are using to process regex.

Answer (score 3):

How about this regex?

```
/((?<!mailto:|=|[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-])[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.‌​-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,64}(?![a-zA-Z]|<\/[aA]>))/
```

Comment: I've given this a try but it does not match anything, in fact, it seems to remove everything for some reason `$data = "example@example.com";

echo preg_replace("/((?<!(?:mailto:|=)[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]*)[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,64})/", "<a href='mailto:$1'>$1</a>", $data);`

As for UK addresses, it does match them so not sure where that came from . . .

Comment: Sorry for that. I've updated the answer with another version of regex. Please try it out.

Comment: +1,Thank you! Anyway it worked if checking using http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ but with javascript I get an error by trying with: new RegExp(/((?<!mailto:|=|[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-])[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.‌​-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,64}(?![a-zA-Z]|<\/[aA]>))/, "g");

Error: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: (regexp): Invalid group.
what could be?

Comment: @ianaz OP is using `preg_replace` which supports **lookbehind** (`(?<!lookup_text)`). JavaScript does not support this functionality.

Comment: Could you please help me to transform that in a js alternative?

Comment: @ianaz If you have a specific problem, please create a new question where people can answer it. If you are the same person as MrJ, please log-in to that account and update this question. I'll be glad to try and work it out.